# Jquery: select event isnt triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas on why this event isnt triggering?

Nothing happens when the SELECT is changed:

```
<select class="filterChange">
    <option value="all">all</option>
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
    <option value="Joan">Joan</option>
    <option value="Eve">Eve Abagail</option>
</select>
```

The Jquery code is the following:"

```
        $('document').ready(function(){   

        // Filter changes
        $( "select.filterChange" ).on( "change", "select", function() {
                alert("boo");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',

                    url: 'inc/changeField.php',
                    data: { 
                        'foo': 'bar', 
                        'var': 'variable'
                    },
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert('wow' + msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
```

I am also running Firebug in Chrome and it gives no errors.  What error checking tool are people using in Chrome?

Comment: Remove the second parameter on `.on`

Comment: passing of second parameter to `.on()` means that to attach the event to that descendant target element. **what jQuery Forum says: A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.**, so remove second parameter in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$( document ).on( "change", "select.filterChange", function() {
            alert("boo");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',

                url: 'inc/changeField.php',
                data: { 
                    'foo': 'bar', 
                    'var': 'variable'
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    alert('wow' + msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

OR

```
$( "select.filterChange" ).on( "change", function() {
                alert("boo");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',

                    url: 'inc/changeField.php',
                    data: { 
                        'foo': 'bar', 
                        'var': 'variable'
                    },
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert('wow' + msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sunilssunilr/qh46vdzn/>)
This is working example.`

```
$('select').on( "change", function() {
 alert("boo");
});
```